# PyCharm thinks that function "open" doesn't have argument "opener"

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is what I have:

[image]

Argument "opener" is not listed in possible function calls' arguments. Is it a PyCharm bug or something else?

PyCharm 2018.3.5 Community Edition, Python 3.6.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Any chance you have another `open()` shadowing the in-built function?

Comment: @AnoopRDesai nope :)

Comment: Interesting, I have the same issue on mine as well. Upon going to definition of `open()` in `builtins.py`, I see `def open(file, mode='r', buffering=None, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True)`.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai Yea, I see the same in `C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2018.3/system/python_stubs/-116048/builtins.py`. It looks like the root of the problem.

Comment: I've occasionally had similar issues with PhpStorm -- sometimes their library specifications get out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be fixed in upcoming 2019.3, EAP is already available: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please help me find the relevant line in changelog here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+193.3519.27+Release+Notes which says that they fixed this?

Comment: I mean, I just want to know for sure they fixed this :) Have you tested the EAP and seen that the error is gone?

Comment: @sanyash There was no issue for this in tracker, `open` definition has been fixed by synchronizing bundled copy of `typeshed` with its master. Since the corresponding sync was done on 3rd of July 2019, every 2019.3 has correct knowledge of `open`. Commit: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/0227f2747c5a07561597081eba4eb006adb41f98